# MaterializeCSS Cards not staying aligned horizontally

Tags: css, angular, sass, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS and outputting into rows of cards with to FAB Links.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s6 m4 l3" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <div class="card sticky-action">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
          <img class="activator responsive-img" src="{{card.image_url}}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content card-wrap-around-name">
          <div class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 text-hide-me">
            {{card.name}}
          </div>
          <i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i>
          <p><a href="#">TBD</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a [routerLink]=''>Add to Decks</a>
          <a [routerLink]=''>Add to Collections</a>
        <div class="card-reveal">
          <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">
            {{card.name}}<i class="material-icons right">close</i>
          </span>
          <p>{{card.text}}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is the HTML - The `card-title` was originally a  but after hunting around SO I moved it to a DIV to see if maybe that's why my CSS wasn't working.

**SASS**

```
.text-hide-me 
  overflow: hidden
  white-space: nowrap
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis
  text-overflow: ellipsis
```

I tried using this CSS to force the 'title' to not wrap-around: I also tried just changing the font-size to 22px; but that's a temp fix because in THIS example titles are only 'so long' but they can be much longer.

[image: Snippet of Card Display]

It's a two-factor issue: Card images will always be one of three sizes:

```
A) No Card Image so it uses my saved one
B) Older cards which are much smaller(Maybe 50-60px)
C) The average card which looks fine, until it's next to A or B
```

I guesstimated that ~420px will align the images, but they're still off a bit - The issue that REALLY affected the output like this is some of the cards have 2+ line 'titles' which cause this trickle effect. CSS seems to not take any affect, I don't know if it's because MaterializeCSS is initializing AFTER my CSS and over-writing it or something else.

Any input would be appreciated - I've tried numerous different tactics (Using  and  but no dice. It is something I'll need to solve for because these cards aren't even long - this one will be problematic (I'm also having an issue with the FAB links being too long but I can emulate the outcome of this to assist)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution is to add dots (...) to the title when it reaches the card's width:

```
.text-hide-me {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

It works with different font sizes and card width.

Working example: https://codepen.io/xristoeftimov/pen/XMgdjO

Comment: Sure enough that works - I'm guessing it's the `overflow: hidden !important;` - I never tried putting an important there.

SASS Has a parse error on `width:100%` every time but removing it, it was still functioning as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a helper class from  https://materializecss.com. 
To truncate long lines of text in an ellipsis, add the class `truncate` to the tag which contains the text.

`<h4 class="truncate">This is an extremely long title that will be truncated</h4>`